# textarea validation and it must be clear every 1 min

Tags: jquery, html, validation, textarea

İ need to do textarea validation like this.I have a some text and i need to do this text write in text area when it will same alert "It's true" when it's field alert... And i need to do auto clear textarea 10000s how can i do.Sorry about my english.I want to do like this

*Who can write this text in 1 min.*

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

```
<textarea> Here it must be same text to up.When its not true its alert and every 1 min clear textarea. </textarea>
```

Who can help me...Thank you...

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. Please show what you have tried to resolve this yourself and exlain problems you have implementing it

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout()?

Read more about it here [Window setTimeout() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var textarea = document.querySelectorAll('textarea')[0];
var result = document.querySelectorAll('#result');
var sampleText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec pellentesque tincidunt est, nec pellentesque ligula. ";
var timer;

function checkText() {
  if(textarea.value === sampleText) {
    console.log('true'); //or alert or whatevs
    window.clearTimeout(timer)
  } else {
    console.log('false'); //or alert or whatevs
  }
} 

timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
    checkText();
},60000); //1 min in ms

textarea.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {
   checkText();
}, false);
```

Comment: To explain, we have a function that will compare your sample text with the textarea - that way you can use it for both scenarios (when the user types or the timer runs out). 

We then start a timer using setTimeout, which will call its calback function after the specified time (in milliseconds). We also add an eventlistener to listen for keyups on the textarea. Each time we fire the function to check the text.

You will also need another function that is called when the timer runs out to clear the text is not the same. Remember you can set textarea.value to something (eg: textarea.value = '')